# Connection is not initialised error in catch block

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In this code

```
    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string localHost = "192.168.10.3";
        string logInDetails = "gp";
        SqlConnection sConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);

        try
        {

            //Checking for the Valid entries in textboxes.
            if ((txtPassword.Text == logInDetails) && (txtUsername.Text == logInDetails))

                //Checking for the appropriate local server address.
                if (txtHost.Text == localHost)
                {
                    sConnection.Open();
                    BindDBDropDown();
                    SetOperationDropDown();
                    PrimaryKeyTable();
                    lblError.Text = "You are connected to the SQL Server....";
                }
                else
                {
                    lblError.Text = "Invalid Credentials";
                }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //All the exceptions are handled and written in the EventLog.
            EventLog log = new EventLog("Application");
            log.Source = "MFDBAnalyser";
            log.WriteEntry(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //To close the connection
            if (sConnection != null)
            {
                sConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

the connection is not initialised error is caught...

In the app.config file I had

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ConnectionString" value="Data Source=192.168.10.3;InitialCatalog=GoalPlanForTrainees;userid=gp;password=gp"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

What might be the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you only open the connection (`sConnection.Open();`) inside the `try`. Of course, the most likely place that an exception will throw **is** this line. Either way, it makes sense that the connection may not necessarily be open in the `catch`.

And if the underlying problem *is* that the call to `.Open()` failed, there isn't much that it **can** do...